# How do I retrieve a template parameter pack given a std::variant?

Tags: c++

example code

```cpp
template<typename T = std::variant<int,double,float>>
void f()
{
}
```

Is it possible to somehow retrieve the std::variant parameter pack as a variadic template argument(or other means)? 
I need to get a list of types I could run a fold expression on, so for the example above I would need something like a `typename... Args` with `int,double,float` in it I could run a fold expression on, given a variant (this part is essential).
Also I really need just the type of the contained types, not a concrete object of those types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a function like this:

```c++
template<class... Vs>
void foo( std::variant<Vs...> const& );
```

you can pass `declval<T>()` to it in order to access the template arguments:

```c++
template<typename T = std::variant<int,double,float>>
void f() {
  using U = decltype(foo(std::declval<T&>()));
}
```

Then you can do whatever you want with `Vs...`.

Update: Now that I have more information here is my newest example:

```c++
template<class T = std::variant<int,double,float>>
void f() {
  print_alternative_types(T{});
}

template<class... Vs>
void print_alternative_types( std::variant<Vs...> const& ) {
  (..., (std::cout << typeid(Vs).name() << '\n'));
}
```

Comment: Note that local T is void in your example.

Comment: that code gives "Error C7515 a fold expression must contain an unexpanded parameter pack" (passing T to the fold expression)

Comment: can you edit the code to show how you would use `(..., (std::cout << typeid(T).name())); ` with it? Because I tried and I'm getting that error

Comment: `std::variant<Vs...> const&>` has a typo, the last `>` ,  but this works. Thanks :)